# How can I lay views out on a xib's UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xib

I have a view that has a horizontally scrolling `UIScrollView`. I have 4 "pages" that I want to show in my scroll view. Can I layout a huge view in Interface Builder that I can scroll across? The problem I'm having while trying to do this is that to design a xib this large across horizontally, you must set the frame of the `UIScrollView` to be the devices `horizontal width * 4`. Therefore the `frame >= the content size` and my scroll view does not scroll. My workaround has been to place all the elements on each of the 4 pages programmatically and adding them to my `UIScrollView` with `addSubView:` What are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

You keep the frame of scroll view as horizontal width only. You should make the content size as horizontal width * 4. Now  set proper frame of the views which you want to put as subviews of that scroll view. Like first subview's frame should have origin.x = horizontal width * 0, second should have origin.x = horizontal width * 1, third should have origin.x = horizontal width * 2 and fourth should have origin.x = horizontal width * 3.

This will eliminate the need of putting subviews programatically.

Comment: Each of my page views has multiple subviews, so these would still need to be added to each of the page views programatically. How can I layout 4 views in xibs and then attach them to my scroll view?

Answer (score -2):

Freeform your xib, design your view